# TextField in scrollpane not displayed correctly

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem displaying multiple TextFields inside a ScrollPane if I Scroll it down. But however if I resize the window by myself the missing TextFields are rendered. I tried multiple ways rendering the missing TextFields but I could not get it working.
[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIndK.png)

This is the Window class I construct when I start the program:

```
public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private Model model;

    public Window() {
        new Thread() {
            {
                setName("Window Thread");
            }
            public void run() {
                initialize();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setSize(frame.getWidth() - 10, frame.getHeight() - 30);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        model = new ChatModel(frame.getWidth() - 10);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(model);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void add(Data d) {
        while (model == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        model.add(d);
    }
}
```

This is a Panel that adds Panels with TextFields I write on:

```
public class Model extends Panel {

    private ArrayList < Line > lines = new ArrayList < Line > ();
    private final int width;

    public Model(int width) {
        this.width = width;
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(getX(), getY(), width, 5 * 30);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    public void add(Data d) {
        synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
            Line cl = new Line(d.txt, width);
            lines.add(cl);
            cl.setBounds(0, lines.size() * 30, width, 30);
            add(cl);
            setSize(width, (lines.size() + 1) * 30);
        }
    }

    private class Line extends Panel {
        TextField txt;

        public ChatLine(String data, int width) {
            setLayout(null);
            txt = new TextField(textUserS);
            txt.setBounds(0, 0, width, 30);
            add(txt);
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: ... 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use AWT components in a Swing application.

Swing Components start with "J" (JTextField, JPanel etc.).

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. For one thing a scroll pane will not work properly if the panel added to the viewport doesn't use a layout manager.

When you dynamically add components to a panel the basic logic is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

There is no need for the synchronized block. Swing components should be updated from the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. If your code is not executed on the `EDT` then you need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to place the code on the `EDT`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.